# CMD ввод переноса строки в консоль

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Есть простенький скрипт:

```
set /p "m=Write: "
echo %m%
```

Требуется ввести текст в переменную *m*, **с сохранением переноса строк**. Допустим ввод:

```
Привет, 
как дела?
```

Надо, чтобы консоль вывела текст точно также. Разумеется, по нажатию enter ввод прекращается. Пробовал #13, alt + 0183 - но безуспешно.

Comment: Делаешь цикл, вводишь построчно, сравниваешь с пустой строкой, конкатенируешь в переменную, а потом выводишь вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/269819/4928642 (вот тут поясняется: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6379619/4928642)

Comment: А почему ответ принял, у меня ж не получилось вывести многострочно?

Comment: @Qwertiy я воспользовался вашим кодом и в цикле вводил по строчно, а затем также и выводил на экран, не стал записывать в переменную

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Многострочный ввод делается циклом как-то так, но вот в саму переменную записать перевод строки у меня не выходит - попробую попозже поправить (пока не удаляю - может кто как основу использует и допилит):

```
echo off
chcp 65001
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

set text=

:INPUT
set line=
set /p line=Write (empty line to finish): 
if "%line%"=="" (goto :DONE)
set text=%text%%line%---
goto :INPUT

:DONE
echo You've entered:
echo %text%
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Так не получится.

Хранить многострочные значения в переменных нельзя, поскольку это предполагает наличие непечатных символов, которые в переменных среды храниться не могут (0x0d,0x0a или \r\n если угодно).

Comment: Ну один раз можно. А вот как это в цикл загнать, я не понял пока... Но пока плюсану.